# Transaction Entity Manager not available Spring/JPA/Hibernate - Pluralsight

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn the Spring framework and have been working through the plural sight tutorials.

I'm currently having problems and not sure how to solve.  Hibernate and JPA have been added to the project, they're created tables fine.  The next part of the tutorial shows how you'd use a Entity Manager and how you'd go about saving the object to the database.

My code mimics his, with the exception that I've updated to the newer version of Spring and have added a ton of comments.

The error I'm receiving is : `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available`

The Entity Manager is called, declared and defined in these snippet.

Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("goal")
public class GoalController {

@Autowired
private GoalService goalService;

@RequestMapping(value = "addGoal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateGoal(@Valid @ModelAttribute("goal") Goal goal,     BindingResult result) {
...
        goalService.save(goal);


    return "redirect:index.jsp";
}
```

}

GoalService is an interface that has a simple `Goal save(Goal goal);` in it which is then implemented by the GoalServiceImpl.

GoalServiceImpl:

```
@Service("goalService")
public class GoalServiceImpl implements GoalService {

@Autowired
private GoalRepository goalRepository;

@Override
public Goal save(Goal goal) {
    return goalRepository.save(goal);
}
```

GoalRepository has the same pattern.

GoalrespositoryImpl:

```
@Repository("goalRepository")
```

public class GoalRepositoryImpl implements GoalRepository {

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public Goal save(Goal goal) {
    entityManager.persist(goal);
    return goal;
}
```

}

I've gone back over the video and can't see where it might be going wrong, I've stepped through it in debug but can't see anything obvious and, even if it were I probably wouldn't see it.

Can anyone shed any light please?

Many thanks.

EDIT:  If I comment out the entity manage, it runs fine, obvious doesn't get saved but it doesn't through the exception.

```
    @Override
public Goal save(Goal goal) {
    //entityManager.persist(goal);
    return null;
}
```

EDIT - DATASOURCE:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fitnessTracker?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Where you have defined datasource??

Comment: @prashantthakre - I've edited the question with the details as there's a large amount of code, thanks for looking.

Comment: Looks like you are messing your `dispatcher-config.xml`  can you check you have correct code like `<mvc:annotation-driven/> and <context:component-scan base-package="<correctpathofyourcontroller>"/>`

Comment: @prashantthakre - in the servlet-config.mxl I have '<mvc:annotation-driven/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight"/>'

Comment: @prashantthakre - I seem to have fixed it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be sheer fluke, I'm not sure...

I moved `

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>`
```

out of the jpaContext.xml and into the servlet-config.xml.  I found  few similar posts hinting that these should be in the same class as where the component-scan takes place.

I don't think this is the whole solution though as I was still having problems.

I then found a random post that referenced having the @Transactional annotation.   I added this `@Override
    @Transactional
    public Goal save(Goal goal) {
        return goalRepository.save(goal);
    }`

and voila..it works.  Whether it should or not is another thing entirely, hopefully this may help someone that stumbles across it if they're also doing the tutorial.